# Как делать hashmap на C под X64?

Tags: c, хеширование, hashmap

Если строка короче 8 байт, что зачастую бывает, например, с именами переменных в интерпретаторах, то она, фактически, может и быть своим хэш-значением? Какой алгоритм хэширования использовать, чтобы не каждый символ строки перебирать, если доступны операции сразу с 8-байтными фрагментами? Допустим, строка априори выровнена на 8 байт и дополнена нулями до длины, кратной 8 байтам. Что подскажете?

Возникло соображение: в большом хэше короткие строки, являющиеся собственным хэш-значением, при делении с остатком будут попадать в букеты в начале хэша, а это плохо.

Возникло соображение: если строку после терминального нуля дополнять символами 0xFF, то первое соображение уже не так важно.

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться тем же алгоритмом, что и в C++? Наверняка компилятор всё соптимизирует. Вроде бы там используется [MurmurHashUnaligned2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murmur2) (по крайней мере в gcc). Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19411888/5812238) узнавали, что именно MurmurHashUnaligned2. А в [английской Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash#Algorithm) даже пример кода на Си есть!

Comment: Медленная для данного приложения. В одном языке, исходники которого я курил, хэш считается как-то типа `c*9+1`, но это посимвольно, а вы предлагаете такую длинную заразу (и там в коде умножения), которая еще называется в вики простой и быстрой. Интересно, почему ее в gcc выбрали? Она точно используется в `std::hash_map`?

Comment: Судя по ответу на enSO точно, по крайней мере в gcc той версии, когда писался ответ. Судя по второму ответу на enSO в том же вопросе сейчас тот алгоритм используется. [Вот](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/hash_bytes.cc#L72-L112) его код. А почему медленная? Думаете компилятор не соптимайзит в быструю, хоть там и есть умножения?

Comment: @diraria, ответ оформлять будете?

Comment: Наверно нет, мне кажется, что вам всё равно не нравится этот алгоритм.

Comment: @diraria, для меня это полезная информация, и ответ может быть полезен другим. Комментарий я не могу выбрать лучшим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться тем же хеширующим алгоритмом, что использует GCC для `std::unordered_map<string, ...>`. Там используется MurmurHashUnaligned2
 ([ruWiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murmur2), [enWiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash)). [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19411888/5812238) ответ на enSO, где узнавали, что именно этот алгоритм используется. А [вот](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/hash_bytes.cc#L72-L112) код этого алгоритма в репозитории gcc на гитхабе. А вот сам алгоритм, скопированный из английской Википедии:

```
uint32_t murmur3_32(const uint8_t* key, size_t len, uint32_t seed) {
  uint32_t h = seed;
  if (len > 3) {
    const uint32_t* key_x4 = (const uint32_t*) key;
    size_t i = len >> 2;
    do {
      uint32_t k = *key_x4++;
      k *= 0xcc9e2d51;
      k = (k << 15) | (k >> 17);
      k *= 0x1b873593;
      h ^= k;
      h = (h << 13) | (h >> 19);
      h = (h * 5) + 0xe6546b64;
    } while (--i);
    key = (const uint8_t*) key_x4;
  }
  if (len & 3) {
    size_t i = len & 3;
    uint32_t k = 0;
    key = &key[i - 1];
    do {
      k <<= 8;
      k |= *key--;
    } while (--i);
    k *= 0xcc9e2d51;
    k = (k << 15) | (k >> 17);
    k *= 0x1b873593;
    h ^= k;
  }
  h ^= len;
  h ^= h >> 16;
  h *= 0x85ebca6b;
  h ^= h >> 13;
  h *= 0xc2b2ae35;
  h ^= h >> 16;
  return h;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно не хешировать, если только содержимое строк достаточно "распределенное", т.е. частота использования всех символов примерно одинаковая. Иначе, как вы написали, будут постоянные коллизии. Можно вместо хеширования, попробовать чем-то зашифровать, к примеру, Блоуфишем, у него как раз блоки по 8 байт, а на выходе почти неотличимая от рандома энтропия, тем самым получить лавинный эффект и не хранить оригинальную строчку.

> Лавинный эффект (англ. Avalanche effect) — понятие в криптографии,
>   обычно применяемое к блочным шифрам и криптографическим хэш-функциям.
>   Важное криптографическое свойство для шифрования, которое означает,
>   что изменение значения малого количества битов во входном тексте или в
>   ключе ведет к «лавинному» изменению значений выходных битов
>   шифротекста. Другими словами, это зависимость всех выходных битов от
>   каждого входного бита.

Подробнее: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лавинный_эффект](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)

Comment: Вероятно, *очень* медленный hashmap на блочном шифре получится.